# Parallel.ForEach throws exception when extracting a zip file

Tags: c#, foreach, zip, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am reading the contents of a zip file and trying to extract them.

```
  var allZipEntries = ZipFile.Open(zipFileFullPath, ZipArchiveMode.Read).Entries;
```

Now if I extract the using Foreach loop this works fine. The drawback is it is equivalent of zip.extract method and I am not getting any advantage when intend to extract all the files.

```
   foreach (var currentEntry in allZipEntries)
        {
            if (currentEntry.FullName.Equals(currentEntry.Name))
            {
                currentEntry.ExtractToFile($"{tempPath}\\{currentEntry.Name}");
            }
            else
            {
                var subDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(currentEntry.FullName));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectoryPath);
                currentEntry.ExtractToFile($"{subDirectoryPath}\\{currentEntry.Name}");
            }

        }
```

Now to take advantage of TPL tried using Parallel.forEach,but that's throwing following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' occurred in System.IO.Compression.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A local file header is corrupt.

```
  Parallel.ForEach(allZipEntries, currentEntry =>
        {
            if (currentEntry.FullName.Equals(currentEntry.Name))
            {
                currentEntry.ExtractToFile($"{tempPath}\\{currentEntry.Name}");
            }
            else
            {
                var subDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(currentEntry.FullName));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectoryPath);
                currentEntry.ExtractToFile($"{subDirectoryPath}\\{currentEntry.Name}");
            }

        });
```

And to avoid this I could use a lock , but that defeats the whole purpose.

```
        Parallel.ForEach(allZipEntries, currentEntry =>
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                if (currentEntry.FullName.Equals(currentEntry.Name))
                {
                    currentEntry.ExtractToFile($"{tempPath}\\{currentEntry.Name}");
                }
                else
                {
                    var subDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(currentEntry.FullName));
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectoryPath);
                    currentEntry.ExtractToFile($"{subDirectoryPath}\\{currentEntry.Name}");
                }
            }

        });
```

Any other or better way around to extract the files?

Comment: The issue is you have read in a single zip file and you are trying to extract it in parallel. What you could do is read it into memory, then extract in parallel, however at the end of the line when windows hits the disk your write IO is still going to be non parallel.

Answer (score 4):

<s>[`ZipFile` is explicitly documented as not guaranteed to be threadsafe for instance members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6)</s>. This is no longer mentioned on the page. [Snapshot from Nov 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20161111235120/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx).

What you're trying to do cannot be done with this library. There *may* be some other libraries out there which do support multiple threads per zip file, but I wouldn't expect it.

You can use multi-threading to unzip multiple files at the same time, but *not* for multiple entries in the same zip file.

Comment: You would then need multiple instances of ZipFile.   It should be OK, since it is just reading the zip..

Comment: While I agree that ZipFile is not thread safe, the linked page does not contain any reference to thread safety.

Comment: @Stuart Axon: "t should be OK, since it is just reading the zip.." - that's not my recent experience; even reading from a ZipArchive in parallel throws errors.

Comment: @MitchWheat Huh, looks like the page has been since updated. It definitely used to say so: https://web.archive.org/web/20161111235120/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Writing/reading in parallel is not a good idea as the hard drive controller will only run the requests one by one. By having multiple threads you just add overhead and queue them all up for no gain.

Try reading the file into memory first, this will avoid your exception however if you benchmark it you may find its actually slower due to the overhead of more threads.

If the file is very large and the decompression takes a long time, running the decompressing in parallel may improve speed, however the IO read/write will not. Most decompression libraries are already multi threaded anyway, so only if this one is not will you have any performance gain from doing this.

Edit: A dodgy way to make the library thread safe below. This runs slower/on par depending on the zip archive which proves the point that this is not something that will benefit from parallelism

```
Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\output\"), File.Delete);

Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
int numberOfThreads = 8;
var clonedZipEntries = new List<ReadOnlyCollection<ZipArchiveEntry>>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    clonedZipEntries.Add(ZipFile.Open(@"c:\temp\temp.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read).Entries);
}
int totalZipEntries = clonedZipEntries[0].Count;
int numberOfEntriesPerThread = totalZipEntries / numberOfThreads;

Func<object,int> action = (object thread) =>
{
    int threadNumber = (int)thread;
    int startIndex = numberOfEntriesPerThread * threadNumber;
    int endIndex = startIndex + numberOfEntriesPerThread;
    if (endIndex > totalZipEntries) endIndex = totalZipEntries;

    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Extracting {clonedZipEntries[threadNumber][i].Name} via thread {threadNumber}");
        clonedZipEntries[threadNumber][i].ExtractToFile($@"C:\temp\output\{clonedZipEntries[threadNumber][i].Name}");
    }

    //Check for any remainders due to non evenly divisible size
    if (threadNumber == numberOfThreads - 1 && endIndex < totalZipEntries)
    {
        for (int i = endIndex; i < totalZipEntries; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Extracting {clonedZipEntries[threadNumber][i].Name} via thread {threadNumber}");
            clonedZipEntries[threadNumber][i].ExtractToFile($@"C:\temp\output\{clonedZipEntries[threadNumber][i].Name}");
        }
    }
    return 0;
};


//Construct the tasks
var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
for (int threadNumber = 0; threadNumber < numberOfThreads; threadNumber++) tasks.Add(Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(action, threadNumber));

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
timer.Stop();

var threaderTimer = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;



Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\output\"), File.Delete);

timer.Reset();
timer.Start();
var entries = ZipFile.Open(@"c:\temp\temp.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read).Entries;
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Extracting {entry.Name} via thread 1");
    entry.ExtractToFile($@"C:\temp\output\{entry.Name}");
}
timer.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Threaded version took: {threaderTimer} ms");
Console.WriteLine($"Non-Threaded version took: {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");


Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is not an answer and well suited for comments

Comment: "Any other or better way around to extract the files?" pretty sure that explains a better way to do it and why.

Comment: How , "That explains" ? I have aready mentioned 3 approcahes in question and you answer(comment) refers to one of those, and not clear on any of approach. How is it different and better than thosel 3 approcches ?

Comment: Your approach is flawed and will not work for the reasons described above.

Comment: What do you mean flawed? Did you read the question? There are 3 approaches and I don't see how 1st and 3rd will not work. Can you write few of lines to show what do you mean by different.

Comment: They work but it defeats the purpose of using parallel. ForEach. Run a benchmark against option 1 and 3 and you will probably find that 1 runs faster even if you modified option 3 to work without the lock (eg read into memory first). The whole point of my answer is there is no performance benefit from attempting to parallelise this problem. You've made the assumption that it will run faster in parallel but it will not.

Comment: There are no assumption that option 3 will run faster than option 1. And that's not even the question. The question is , How/Can we use option 2 without any error and with out using a lock as in option 3 as it defeats whole purpose.

Comment: If it won't run faster then why do you want to use Parallel.ForEach? It adds overhead for no gain. If you want to run it without a lock you need to read the zip file into memory first, create multiple copies of it in memory, then pass multiple instances into your ForEach loop. This will be slower than option 1 though, hence there is no point which is what I've been trying to explain.

Comment: I added an example of how you could make it work. However I advise against it as it will almost certainly be slower and less maintainable.

Comment: What clonedZipEntries is doing?  Why do you even need that. if you can not draw or provide a understandable solution , there is no point in providing theories as msdn already have them , And here is some reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Because as the library is not thread safe you must make multiple clones of it. Once again, what you are trying to do will not work. Please read my original answer along with the other answer as to why Parallel.ForEach is not appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I posted a working example showing how to make it thread safe. The benchmark shows the performance is slower/the same depending on the archive, eg this is not suitable for Parallel.ForEach

Comment: I know TPL or parallels are bad idea when on IO or Database operations. But this has been a limitation since it has been introduced , but was checking if there has been any updates to get it working. Probably , this is not the limitation of TPL but the OS itself.

Comment: It is not a limitation of the language. It is due to how a harddrive physically works. It can only write one sector a time, hence any IO operations will queue regardless of what you do in the software or OS.